# How can I clone a GameObject (cube) and move it forward or backward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

And clone I mean including also the scale of the scaled cubes.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameObjectToRaise;
    public float raiseAmount;
    public float raiseTotal = 50;
    public float speed = 2;
    public static bool raised = false;

    public int x, z;
    private List<GameObject> cubes;
    private GameObject go;

    public bool randomColor;
    public Color[] colorChoices;

    Vector3 lp;
    Vector3 ls;

    // Use this for initialization

    void Start()
    {
        lp = gameObjectToRaise.transform.localPosition;
        ls = gameObjectToRaise.transform.localScale;

        GameObject cube = CUBE.CreatePrimitive(CUBE.CubePivotPoint.UPLEFT);
        GameObject cube1 = CUBE.CreatePrimitive(CUBE.CubePivotPoint.UPRIGHT);

        cube.transform.position = new Vector3(lp.x, lp.y, lp.z);
        cube1.transform.position = new Vector3(lp.x, lp.y, lp.z);
        cube1.transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);

        StartCoroutine(scaleCube(cube.transform));
        StartCoroutine(scaleCube(cube1.transform));

        GameObject clone1 = Instantiate(cube);
        GameObject clone2 = Instantiate(cube1);

        clone1.transform.localScale = cube.transform.localScale;
        clone2.transform.localScale = cube1.transform.localScale;
        clone1.transform.position = new Vector3(lp.x, lp.y, lp.z - 15);
        clone2.transform.position = new Vector3(lp.x - 15, lp.y, lp.z);
    }

    IEnumerator scaleCube(Transform trans)
    {
        while (raiseAmount < raiseTotal)
        {
            raiseAmount += 1;
            trans.localScale += new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    public class CUBE
    {
        public enum CubePivotPoint
        {
            MIDDLE, RIGHT, LEFT, UP, DOWN, FORWARD, BACK, UPLEFT,
            UPRIGHT, FORWARDUP, BACKUP
        }

        //Takes CubePivotPoint Enum as pivot point
        public static GameObject CreatePrimitive(CubePivotPoint pivot)
        {
            //Calculate pivot point
            Vector3 cubePivot = createPivotPos(pivot);

            //Create cube with the calculated pivot point
            return createCubeWithPivotPoint(cubePivot);
        }

        //Takes Vector3 as pivot point
        public static GameObject CreatePrimitive(Vector3 pivot)
        {
            //Create cube with the calculated pivot point
            return createCubeWithPivotPoint(pivot);
        }

        private static Vector3 createPivotPos(CubePivotPoint pivot)
        {
            switch (pivot)
            {
                case CubePivotPoint.MIDDLE:
                    return new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
                case CubePivotPoint.LEFT:
                    return new Vector3(0.5f, 0f, 0f);
                case CubePivotPoint.RIGHT:
                    return new Vector3(-0.5f, 0f, 0f);
                case CubePivotPoint.UP:
                    return new Vector3(0f, 0.5f, 0f);
                case CubePivotPoint.DOWN:
                    return new Vector3(0f, -0.5f, 0f);
                case CubePivotPoint.FORWARD:
                    return new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0.5f);
                case CubePivotPoint.BACK:
                    return new Vector3(0f, 0f, -0.5f);
                case CubePivotPoint.UPLEFT:
                    return new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
                case CubePivotPoint.UPRIGHT:
                    return new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
                case CubePivotPoint.FORWARDUP:
                    return new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
                case CubePivotPoint.BACKUP:
                    return new Vector3(0f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
                default:
                    return default(Vector3);
            }
        }

        private static GameObject createCubeWithPivotPoint(Vector3 pivot)
        {
            //Create a cube postioned at 0,0,0
            GameObject childCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            //Create an empty parent object
            GameObject parentObject = new GameObject("CubeHolder");
            //Move the parent object to the provided pivot postion 
            parentObject.transform.position = pivot;
            //Make the childcube to be child child of the empty object (CubeHolder)
            childCube.transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform);
            return parentObject;
        }
    }
}
```

In the enum I added UPLEFT and UPRIGHT.

The problem is that the pivot. Now I want to clone this two walls or cubes and move them each one to the other direction so it will be 4 walls.

Or maybe I don't need the clones and not the UPLEFT and UPRIGHT at all?
With the clones I wanted to close the walls.

Without the clones part what I'm getting is:

[image: Walls]

Now I want to add two more walls to close it like a building.
And I prefer to make it moving (scale changing) like I'm doing with the cubes now.

The problem is how to add the next two walls? Another pivot? Using the same pivot? Making a clone and just position the two walls?

Update

What i tried so far is in the Start function i did:

```
void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(gameObjectToRaise, new Vector3(i * 1.0f, lp.y, lp.z), Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate(gameObjectToRaise, new Vector3(lp.x, i * 1.0f, lp.z), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

The second Instantiate is working fine the new gameobjects come out from the gameObjectToRaise. But the first line of the Instantiate:

```
Instantiate(gameObjectToRaise, new Vector3(i * 1.0f, lp.y, lp.z), Quaternion.identity);
```

Put the new gameonects in another position on the terrain not close to the gameObjectToRaise. Why is that ?

Comment: This looks like a lot of code for just placing a few walls. Anyway, if you really want your code to be like this, I'd suggest looking into [Flag Enums](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for your pivot points so you can combine directions in your switch. That way you don't have to create new enum values everytime you want to place a wall in another direction, you'd only have to add something to your switch.

Comment: @PJvG In what parts i could make the code to be minimum ? I mean if it's a lot of code how could i narrow the code ? Using enum for the walls is not a good way ?

Comment: I think if you get rid of the `CUBE` class and use this `Instantiate` method: [`public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) instead of the one you're using now, you'll can do the same with a lot less code. Feed your `Vector3`s that you had in the switch directly into the `Instantiate` method, or better: provide them to your script using the Inspector. You can even feed your parent object directly into the `Instantiate` method.

Comment: @PJvG I updated my question now in the bottom with what i did. I have a problem with the first Instantiate when changing the axis x it's positioning the new gameobject in other position then the gameObjectToRaise somewhere else in the terrain. Not sure why it happen when changing the axis x.

Comment: As a side note (unrelated to your issue), you might also want to read about [Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#. Generally, only parameter and field names should start with a lowercase letter, all other names (e.g. method names) should be capitalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the position of the `gameObjectToRaise` as followed:

```
Instantiate(gameObjectToRaise, new Vector3(lp.x + i * 1.0f, lp.y, lp.z), Quaternion.identity);
Instantiate(gameObjectToRaise, new Vector3(lp.x, lp.y + i * 1.0f, lp.z), Quaternion.identity);
```

Note the "+ operators" I used in the code example.

Comment: The whole idea of using the CUBE class in the original code in my question was since i wanted to scale only one direction/side of the gameobjec/s. Using your solution with the loop is less code but it's scaling both sides again.

Comment: It would be nice if the person who downvoted me could tell me why they downvoted...